# How do I have user's response to raw_input( ) access a string of the same name?

Tags: python, string, filenames, raw-input

I am attempting to have two pieces of user input become parts of a filename that my Python script will then access.

For example, I want to use the pieces of user input to construct: date_time_place.txt.  I know I can do that by concatenating strings.

I ask the user for raw_input() for date and time, but I have named the date and time options they can use:

```
date1 = yesterday
date2 = today
date3 = tomorrow

time1 = morning
time2 = afternoon
time3 = evening
```

I specify that the user must enter his or her response as date# or time#.

What I want is to be able to use his or her response to obtain what date# or time# already is assigned to be.  How does one go about such a thing?

Comment: You generally **don't do that**. Use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you for elaborating a bit!  I'm new to using Python, so your explanation was very helpful.  I'll be accepting it as soon as I am able to do so.

Comment: @sweeneyrod, thank you, but for newcomers like myself, a more detailed explanation would have been beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you *can*, you should not attempt this. Put your variables in a dictionary instead;

```
dates = {
    'date1': yesterday,
    'date2': today,
    'date3': tomorrow,
}

times = {
    'time1': morning,
    'time2': afternoon,
    'time3': evening,
}
```

Now access is as simple as `dates[userstring]` or `times[userstring]`.

You *could* access local variables with the [`locals()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals), globals with [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) (both return a dictionary), but you then cannot constrain the names they have access to.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = ["morning","afternoon", "evening"]

print """please choose one 0:morning
1:afternoon
2:evening """

daytime = time[int(raw_input())]
```

it is a sample solution. check for out of index values and non-int value exceptions.

Comment: Using Python 2's `input()` is a huge security hole; it was removed in Python 3 and replaced with `raw_input()`.

Comment: can you provide a link please? :)

Comment: Thanks for the great info, i did some research and(for those interested):
input() basically calls eval() every time, so one could do anything if you use input():
example:
`>> input("Your name?")`
`__import__("os").system("rm -rf /") #imports os, runs "rm -rf /"(delete root dir)`